# What kind of optimizations does the Swift compiler perform?

Tags: swift, compilation, compiler-optimization

I would love to know how to read the Swift compiler, but I can't read C++ and it's quite a lot.

Is there a list of optimisations the Swift compiler performs, so that I can more effectively optimise my code or allow my code to be optimised?

Comment: It's really not that simple, and having such a list won't help much. For one, the optimizer doesn't concern itself with your Swift code. It operates on the Swift Intermediate Language (SIL) produced by SILgen, and the LLVM code produced after that

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov that's disappointing. Do you have a link where I can find the optimiser for the SIL?

Comment: Why's it disappointing? Implementing code optimization at the Swift language layer would require the optimizer constantly be changed with every change to the language (of which there are *many*). SIL acts as a buffer between the two, so it isolates the optimizer from the high level changes of Swift

Comment: Also, optimizing at LLVM level means that Swift benefits from the optimizations already implemented for all other supported LLVM languages, like C, C++, Objective C, Rust, etc.

Comment: I don't have a link for it, sorry